# How can I boot the RedHat Linux Installer on a Mac Pro?

Tags: macos, installation, redhat-enterprise-linux

I have an early 2008 mac pro. I want to install redhat 5.8 on it, single boot only.

I have a new harddrive in the machine but I can't seem to boot my redhat 5.8 installer. I've held option on boot, selected the CD, but nothing ever happens (screen stays white/grayish). I've held down C as well, but nothing. I also tried a fedora disk, same thing.

How do I get the redhat installer to boot?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use rEFIt: http://refit.sourceforge.net

If you're running Lion you'll need to install refit manually as shown here: http://www.cvol.ca/2012/02/getting-refit-working-on-lion.html

Comment: Fortunately it can be done without rEFit. I was using an USB-external optical drive to boot from the installer, but I found out there are problems with the EFI and doing that. I found an internal SATA optical drive to use and the installer booted up with no problems, installed just fine, and works as it should now (right after the EFI screen it kicks into redhat).